# Changing prompt from lts to normal

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

I'm currently running 14.04lts but i want to upgrade to 15.04. The things is that in the file where you change the prompt=lts to normal, when I try to change it to normal i can't save it and i just want to know how.

Comment: If you want to upgrade to newer version, you don't just change a particular file. Changing a file doesn't necessarily make programs and OS change to newer version.  Follow this answer right here:  http://askubuntu.com/a/601974/295286

Answer (score 5):

Edit the file with `sudo` rights

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

---

As you can see here

```
ls -la /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 832 Feb 26 17:30 /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

the file is only writable for `root`.